Eigenvalues of the sum of a diagonal matrix and a non-symmetric matrix both with non-positive eigenvalues
I'm currently working on the following problem:
I want to say something about the eigenvalues of the sum of two matrices $A$ and $B$, where $A$ is a diagonal matrix with only negative diagonal elements and $B$ is a non-symmetric matrix with non-positive eigenvalues (i.e. some eigenvalues of $B$ can be zero).
I know that there are some famous results for the eigenvalues of $C=A+B$ if both are hermitian matrices (Weyl inequality, Horns conjecture), but are there any results if at least one of two added matrices is non-hermitian? Is there a counterexample where $C$ can have positive eigenvalues in my case?

Random counterexample:
\begin{align*}
&C=\pmatrix{-18&0\\ 0&-2}+\pmatrix{-1&2\\ 1&-1}\pmatrix{-3&12\\ 0&-3}\pmatrix{1&2\\ 1&1}
=\pmatrix{-33&-12\\ 12&7},\\
&C\pmatrix{1\\ -3}=\pmatrix{3\\ -9}=3\pmatrix{1\\ -3}.
\end{align*}

Thanks! Are there results in the literature for some special cases of non-Hermitian matrices?
